# JAMA Library Singular Value Decomposition algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, svd, jama

Do you know where I can find SVD(Singular Value Decomposition) algorithm which the implementation is found in JAMA (Java Matrix Library)?

I have found and downloaded JAMA, and I can see the source code there, but I have difficulty in understanding how the codes work or why it goes like that, I mean I need the SVD algorithm which used in JAMA for better understanding about implementing SVD on computer. Because implementing SVD on computer have different approach(way) than doing(solve) it manually by hand.

So, do you know where I can find the algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the JAMA implementation is a Java port of a Fortran routine originally called `DSVDC` from the old [LINPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK) library. AFAIK, DSVDC is based on the classic bidiagonalization method first proposed by Golub and Kahan in 1965.